# Tidying up a query using ARel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arel

I have an existing Rails 2.3.x application that uses the follow block of code to sum up 4 columns of data for a given data range.

```
results = connection.execute(<<-SQL)
  SELECT sum(total_hours), sum(expected_hours), sum(total_billable), sum(expected_billable)
  FROM `timesheets`
  WHERE (`timesheets`.`week_starting` BETWEEN '#{Date.today.beginning_of_year}' AND '#{Date.today.monday}')
SQL
total_hours, expected_hours, total_billable, expected_billable = results.fetch_row.map(&:to_f).map(&:to_d)
```

As I'm upgrading to Rails 3 and mysql2 the fetch_row method no longer exists so I thought this would be a good chance to tidy this query up using ARel.

Does anyone know how to do this query using ARel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Written in a modular "builder" style, allowing refactoring into reusable scopes:

```
Timesheet.where('week_starting >= ?', Date.today.beginning_of_year).
  where('week_starting < ?', Date.today.monday).
  select('SUM(total_hours) as total_hours').
  select('SUM(expected_hours) as expected_hours').
  select('SUM(total_billable) as total_billable').
  select('SUM(total_hours) as expected_billable')
```

Comment: I think this might be the right way to do it but it seems a bit odd that it returns a Timesheet object with methods relating to the summed values. Ideally it would just be returning a hash of the summed values.

Comment: Then pop a ".attributes" on the end if it bothers you.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify the where clause like this:

```
date_range = Date.today.beginning_of_year..Date.today.monday
Timesheet.where(:week_starting => date_range).
```

This turns into a `BETWEEN` clause.

Comment: Good call, I've already got a 'between' scope on the Timesheet model which does pretty much this. Combining this with Andrew's answer seems to do the job. Thanks